# structuredClone with function giving an error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, deep-copy, structured-clone

I want to do a deep copy of an object which also has function as keys.

So I do

```
deepCopy = structuredClone(existingObjWithFns);
```

However when this runs, I get the below error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': function MyFunction()

Comment: Yep, you can't structuredClone a function.

Answer (score 5):

Function objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to throws a DataCloneError exception.

for more information, you can read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone)

if you want to deep clone nested objects, you should make a function to check the type of all of them and copy them one by one.

Lodash `deepClone` work with all types, function,s and Symbol copied by reference I suggest that you use `Lodash`.

but with the `object.assign()` you can do it faster:

```
const target = { a: () => { return 1 }, b: 2 };
const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);

console.log(target);
// Expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }

console.log(returnedTarget === target);
// Expected output: true
```

for more information about object cloning you can follow [this link](https://javascript.info/object-copy#cloning-and-merging-object-assign)

Comment: So there is no way to clone such objects ?

Comment: Will Object.assign do nested copy ?

Comment: I edit my answer you can do it with the object.assign().

Comment: Lodash deepClone also works with nested functions and other

Answer (score -2):

**structuredClone** throwing error in browser, so i found alternate way using lodash npm package

```
npm i lodash 

const _ = require('lodash');
   
var obj = {
    anyField: 23
};
   
// Here is structured clone so it won't get copied
var deepCopy = _.cloneDeep(obj);
   
console.log('Comparing original with'
    + ' deep ', obj === deepCopy);
   
obj.anyField = 10; // Changing original value
   
console.log('After changing original value');
   
console.log("Original value ", obj);
   
console.log("Deep Copy value ", deepCopy);
```

Comment: incorrect. https://caniuse.com/?search=structuredClone